# Django Date Range Query

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-views

I have a table that holds VM analytic data, every time the data is entered it inserts a time-stamp. The data is entered every hour and truncated at the 30day mark. I need to write a Django query to search a given amount of days based on a posted integer from a customer.

Thus the customer submits the number 7 and the the Django query returns the last 7 days data. I was looking into the documentation about dates but it doesn't seem like it will do what I want.

I really just need some help here, on where to look or even if its possible with Django.

This is my current query:

```
vms = VmStatHistories.objects.filter(customer_id = customer_id).order_by('vm_id').distinct('vm_id').filter(datetime =  datetime.datetime.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=number_of_days))
```

The models field:

```
class VmStatHistories(models.Model):
    vm_stat_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    vm_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customers)
    vm_name = models.CharField(max_length=4000)
    read_request = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    write_request = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    cpu_usage_ghz = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    memory_consumed_mb = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    memory_active_mb = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    memory_swap_mb = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    bytes_sent_kbps = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    bytes_received_kbps = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    disk_usage_mbps = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    provisioned_ram_gb = models.BigIntegerField()
    provisioned_cores = models.BigIntegerField()
    provisioned_storage_gb = models.BigIntegerField()
    consumed_storage_gb = models.BigIntegerField()
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'vm_stat_histories'

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
      return self.vm_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base query is almost right. Just use `datetime__gte=datetime.datetime.today() -datetime.timedelta(days=number_of_days)` in your `filter` call instead of `datetime=...`. As written, you're asking for data timestamped at exactly the specified number of days ago, not data from that number of days up until the present.